# Need help debugging, code compiles but won't run

Tags: java, debugging, user-interface, nullpointerexception

Hey I could use help debugging this program. The code is not mine, it is from an answer to a question and I wanted to try it but I get a NullPointerException and can't figure out where the problem is. I think the problem may be image paths but I am not sure so I could use help.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CircleImages {

private int score = 0;
private JTextField scoreField = new JTextField(10);

public CircleImages() {
    scoreField.setEditable(false);

    final ImageIcon[] icons = createImageIcons();
    final JPanel iconPanel = createPanel(icons, 8);

    JPanel bottomLeftPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
    bottomLeftPanel.add(new JLabel("Score: "));
    bottomLeftPanel.add(scoreField);

    JPanel bottomRightPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
    JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");
    bottomRightPanel.add(newGame);
    JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
    bottomRightPanel.add(quit);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    bottomPanel.add(bottomLeftPanel);
    bottomPanel.add(bottomRightPanel);

    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reset(iconPanel, icons);
            score = 0;
            scoreField.setText(String.valueOf(score));
        }
    });

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(iconPanel);
    frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void reset(JPanel panel, ImageIcon[] icons) {
    Component[] comps = panel.getComponents();
    Random random = new Random();
    for(Component c : comps) {
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel button = (JLabel)c;
            int index = random.nextInt(icons.length);
            button.setIcon(icons[index]);
        }
    }
}

private JPanel createPanel(ImageIcon[] icons, int gridSize) {
    Random random = new Random();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(gridSize, gridSize));
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize * gridSize; i++) {
        int index = random.nextInt(icons.length);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icons[index]);
        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                score += 1;
                scoreField.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            }
        });
        label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY, 2));
        panel.add(label);
    }
    return panel;
}

private ImageIcon[] createImageIcons() {
    String[] files = {"DarkGrayButton.png",
        "BlueButton.png",
        "GreenButton.png",
        "LightGrayButton.png",
        "OrangeButton.png",
        "RedButton.png",
        "YellowButton.png"
    };
    ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[files.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        icons[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/circleimages/" + files[i]));
    }
    return icons;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CircleImages();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post the entire exception stack trace?

Comment: An important skill that you should learn is how to use a debugger. It will help you out quite a bit in the future.

Comment: This is as much of it as I can post: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at CircleImages.createImageIcons(CircleImages.java:90)
 at CircleImages.<init>(CircleImages.java:15)
 at CircleImages$3.run(CircleImages.java:98)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
icons[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/circleimages/" + files[i]));
```

You don't have the required images in your project, so `getClass().getResource()` will return `null` and you will have a `NullPointerException` in the constructor of `ImageIcon`.

What you have to do is put the following files in your project:

- /circleimages/DarkGrayButton.png
- /circleimages/BlueButton.png
- /circleimages/GreenButton.png
- /circleimages/LightGrayButton.png
- /circleimages/OrangeButton.png
- /circleimages/RedButton.png
- /circleimages/YellowButton.png

Comment: What do you mean by put them in my project? Like have them in the same folder as the class? Right now I have the images in the same folder as the class.

Comment: @user3390522 You have to put them in your classpath, in a folder called `circleimages` (usually in the folder `src` or `src/java`). If your class is in a package, it will not be in the same folder as the class.

Comment: @user3390522 You are welcome. Could you please mark the answer as accepted (the green check) ?